# Unexpected NPE thrown when trying to put resultset of query into a map

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I am getting a Null pointer exception at the shown line in the following code when i am putting the values from resultset into a map, it works most times, but sometimes it is throwing NPE, it is a service type application which runs in the background and every method opens a connection to the database and close it after use. There is a synchronized lock for every method so that no conflict occurs during connecting to DB.

```
public Configuration getConfiguration() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_settings;";
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    synchronized (_synchObject){
    try {
        open();
        PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
           >>line 495: map.put(rs.getString("Field"), rs.getString("Value"));   //NPE is thrown in this line: 495
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
    return new Configuration(map);
  }
```

The method open() here simply creates the connection to the DB-

```
 private void open() throws SQLException {
    String connectionString = ConfigSettings.getInstance().getDatabaseConnectionString();
    conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
}
```

The Exception thrown -

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.buildIndexMapping(ResultSetImpl.java:683)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1042)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5202)
at com.twora.entryexit.db.DatabaseAccess.getConfiguration(DatabaseAccess.java:495)
at com.twora.entryexit.model.Configuration.getInstance(Configuration.java:33)
at com.twora.entryexit.service.runnables.IntervalledService.runSpecific(IntervalledService.java:33)
at com.twora.entryexit.service.runnables.RunningService.run(RunningService.java:38)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am running the query once in each run and reading resultset immediately after that. What should I do to overcome this?

Comment: com.twora.entryexit.db.DatabaseAccess.getConfiguration(DatabaseAccess.java:495) From this line I can't figure out which line is 495 in method getConfiguration

Comment: i have added a comment beside the line throwing NPE (line 495)

Comment: If that's the complete and correct stack trace, the NPE is occurring in one of the `getString()` calls.  Can you rewrite that section to do the `getString()` calls before the `map.put()` and store the values in temporary `String`s, so you can see which one is failing?

Comment: Yes, in getString() you need to pass either numeric value which is index for column in table or name of the column, I think there is mistake in getString

Comment: i have added the line tag @nikeshjoshi,@Jim do you mean inside the loop? okay i can do that, but then again, may be i have to wait for a undefined time to get the NPE again as it is thrown rarely.

Comment: "Field" and "Value" are two column name of the tbl_settings here, no spelling mismatch here @nikeshjoshi

Comment: Try to print getString("Field") and getString("Value") before putting them to the hashMap :) :) ,,,,, Also print ResultSet Object to make sure it is not null

Comment: okay @nikeshjoshi , i will do that and give updates. Thanks

Comment: @JimGarrison I am printing two strings as you said just before map.put(), to see if any string is null, i will give updates, thanks.

Comment: Based on the stack trace the exception is happening inside one of the calls to `rs.getString()`, in MySQL code, which shouldn't happen unless there's a bug in the driver.

Comment: Maybe you should try to write field names with lower case (like "field" and "value"). Stacktrace gives me an idea that it somehow can't find necessary columns.

Comment: @MaximKreschishin Thanks, i am changing it but don't think upper case is an issue here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an exception in the code that builds the three maps in the result set which map column names and labels to their index in the query.  This has nothing to do with the calls to getString.

What is most likely happening is that your thread synchronization is flawed and you have two threads working on the same result set object at the same time.  This happens because the result set comes from the connection object and you have two threads using the same result set object from the same connection at the same time.

The maps in that result set are cleared when "close" is called in the result set.  So you have one thread closing the result set while another thread is still using it.  This also explains why it works some of the time, it all depends on the timing.

I can see in your code that the object you use to synchronize is not clear.  You need to ensure that you are not using the same connection object in two separate threads at the same time, and your synchronization is failing to do this at this time.

Comment: I was not thinking from this direction. Thanks, For clarity, Are you implying that there may be a method which is not inside synchronized statement?

Comment: I saw a method which was opening , working on result set and closing the connection to DB that was not inside the synchronized statement. Changed it, now running the test. Will post updates. Thanks @Sean

Comment: I am accepting this as answer as it points me to think in the right direction, and no more NPE is thrown so far.

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple threads using the same connection, they all must synchronize on the same object whenever they are using the connection.  So you must have them all inside synchronized blocks or synchronized methods.  In addition, the object used for synchronization (_synchObject in your code) must be the exact same object for all such synchronized blocks and methods.